# Php form not pulling correct email address into the from section

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull the email address of the user into the $from section but I'm not having any luck. Every thing works properly except the $from section it isn't pulling the desired email address. Here's an example of what I'm seeing in my in box.

Subject:    OffPod
From:   OffPod@p3nlhg757.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (I would like this section to pull the E-mail below i.e. mcginndaniel123@gmail.com)
Date:   Tue, Aug 20, 2013 10:44 am
To: daniel@purplebottlemedia.com

From: Daniel
E-Mail: mcginndaniel123@gmail.com
Message:
Testing Testing

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $from = 'From:';
 $to = 'daniel@purplebottlemedia.com'; 
 $subject = 'OffPod';

 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
  } else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `$from` other than setting it to a string.

Comment: The fourth parameter for `mail` is a string containing mail headers; you can use that to override the existing From header. You're currently passing in the string `From:` - try concatenating `$name` to it, too: `'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";`

Comment: That said - there are libraries that will help you create emails, rather than having to generate them yourself. Have a look at PEAR, for one: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected

Comment: That worked for the name. 
From: Daniel@p3nlhg758.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net                       How would I add the email address after the name. Would I add $email after $name like this $from = 'From: ' . $name . $email . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

According to the mail() docs on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php you should be adding the From email address in the additional headers, which is the 4th parameter in mail. Example:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You are putting the $from variable where the additional headers should be. You also have only set the $from variable to be "From:" without the actual from address. Here's how you could fix that

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $to = 'daniel@purplebottlemedia.com';
 $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
 $subject = 'OffPod';

 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
  } else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$from = 'From: '.$email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are taken one variable $from = 'From:'; it take only one string value not contains email format.

Try this

```
$from = $email;
```

Comment: Ok, I get it that worked perfectly. Now time to code the spam filter. Thanks for all the help!!